# Dimension mismatch for numpy array

Tags: pandas, numpy, tensorflow, linear-regression

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split


df = pd.read_csv('FuelConsumption.csv', skip_blank_lines = True)
feature = np.asanyarray(df[["ENGINE SIZE","CYLINDERS","Mcity", "Mhwy", "Mcmb", "McmbMPG"]])
label = np.asanyarray(df['CO2'])


X_train, X_test, Y_train, Y_test = train_test_split(feature, label, test_size=0.2)


learning_rate = 0.01
training_epochs = 1000
cost_history = np.empty(shape=[1],dtype=float)

n_dim = feature.shape[1]
print(feature.shape)
print(label.shape)

X = tf.placeholder(tf.float32,[None,n_dim])
Y = tf.placeholder(tf.float32,[None,1])
W = tf.Variable(tf.ones([n_dim,1]))

init = tf.global_variables_initializer()

y_ = tf.matmul(X, W)
cost = tf.reduce_mean(tf.square(y_ - Y))
training_step = tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(learning_rate).minimize(cost)

sess = tf.Session()
sess.run(init)

for epoch in range(training_epochs):
  sess.run(training_step,feed_dict={X:X_train,Y:Y_train})
  cost_history = np.append(cost_history,sess.run(cost,feed_dict={X: X_train,Y: Y_train}))

plt.plot(range(len(cost_history)),cost_history)
plt.axis([0,training_epochs,0,np.max(cost_history)])
plt.show()
```

I am using above code to perform linear regression. I would like to pass the training data into tensorflow placeholders. When I run the above code I am getting the following error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:/Users/snaglapu/Desktop/LinReg/LinReg.py", line 39, in <module>
sess.run(training_step,feed_dict={X:X_train,Y:Y_train})
File "C:\Users\snaglapu\Desktop\LinReg\venv\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\client\session.py", line 929, in run
run_metadata_ptr)
File "C:\Users\snaglapu\Desktop\LinReg\venv\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\client\session.py", line 1128, in _run
str(subfeed_t.get_shape())))
ValueError: Cannot feed value of shape (873,) for Tensor 'Placeholder_1:0', which has shape '(?, 1)'
```

Dimension of features is (1096, 6). why not the dimention of labels is (1092,1) but (1092, )?

Comment: whats the dimension for X_train and Y_train? can you print it too?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Reshape your training data `Y_train`. It needs to be 2D:

```
Y_train = Y_train.reshape(-1, 1)
```

You can even start earlier:

```
label = label.reshape(-1, 1)
```

The reason is that `label` is only one column, so stays one column during the training/test split. But you need a 2D array for tensorflow.